# Simple relative frequency calculation, confusing wording

Tags: distributions, self-study

I am admittedly doing homework, but two problems are worded in such a way that is confusing me. Part (b) asks, "Determine the probability that an individual who has saved for retirement has saved less than $50,000. Use relative frequencies."

Part (c) asks, "Determine the probability that a randomly chosen individual has saved less then $50,000 toward retirement."

As far as I can tell, both parts are asking me to do the exact same thing. But that can't be right....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like part (b) is asking for a conditional probability while part (c) is asking for a marginal probability.

That is, part (b) is saying: given that an individual has saved for retirement, what is the probability that he/she has saved less than 50k.  So, the probability among only those who have saved for retirement.

In contrast, part (c) wants the probability that an individual among the entire population (including those who haven't saved for retirement) has saved less than 50k.

Comment: You just beat me to the same answer: part (b) is about P(savings < $50K | universe of people who have saved)

Comment: Ahh yes, I see now. The problem says that only 69% of workers have saved for retirement. I suck at statistics. Now I need to figure out how to calculate the probability for this.

Comment: Could you please also help with http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17098/i-know-the-probability-of-an-outcome-in-a-sample-how-to-apply-to-population