# I know the probability of an outcome in a sample, how to apply to population?

Tags: distributions, self-study

I admittedly am horrible at statistics. I know that the probability of an individual who has saved for retirement has saved less then 50,000 USD is 16.4% according to my sample data, but only 69% of workers say they have saved for retirement. So what is the probability for a random person selected from the entire population to have saved less than 50,000 USD?

So that means 31% of the population admits to not saving anything (which is less then 50,000 USD), so the probability of a random person selected from the entire population having saved less than 50,000 USD for retirement is actually greater than 16.4% - but I don't know how to calculate what it is more precisely.

This is homework, but I am so lost....

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Suppose you had 1000 workers.

Then you might think about $690=1000\times 0.69$ of them had saved something for retirement and $310=1000-690$ had saved nothing.

Of those, about 16.4% or $690 \times 0.164$ had saved something for retirement but less than $50,000. What is that as a percentage of 1000?

And how many had saved less than $50,000 including those who had save nothing?  What is that as a percentage of 1000?

Comment: +1 People tend to think intuitively and well about actual numbers, rather than probabilities, so this method of converting the information into (hypothetical) numbers often helps with Bayesian problems.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at both your posts, you probably want to start here: [Bayes theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) and work through the examples half-way down carefully.

Edit: [This](http://people.hofstra.edu/stefan_waner/tutorialsf3/unit6_6.html) looks like a reasonable beginners' tutorial.

Comment: Yeah, we learned about Baye's Theorem, that at least tells me which formula to use. But of course it's one of the hardest formulas in the book that never made any sense to me... arg. I don't know how to read formula notation. I need it explained without that. Any stats for dummies resources out there that explain Bayes in a simplistic manner without the fancy greek stuff everywhere?

Comment: I found this: http://stattrek.com/lesson1/bayes.aspx

But I still don't understand :(

Comment: I appreciate your help, though. I'm paying a tutor and trying my best, but I just don't get these formulas. The ones that are built into Excel and the calculator I can do, but ones like this I am lost.

Answer (score 2):

you may have to check the sample data more closely, but I think the 16.4% is a "conditional" percentage.  That is, 16.4% of the sampled units *who said they saved for retirement* have saved less than $50,000$.  If we write this as a fraction, it may help your understanding:

$$\frac{\text{Number of sampled units saving >0 and <50000}}{\text{Number of sampled units saving >0}}\times 100\text{%}=16.4\text{%}$$

(The denominator here may or may not include the sampled units with exactly $0$ savings, which is why you need to check the question).  And your 69% would be obtained by:

$$\frac{\text{Number of sampled units saving >0}}{\text{Number of sampled units saving >0 or exactly 0}}\times 100\text{%}=69\text{%}$$

I think this is the difficulty you are having.  Note that the numerator of the second probability is the same as the denominator of the first probability*, so if you multiply them, they cancel.  To further complete the question, is easiest done via a "decision process".  We must first:

1. Decide whether the person admits to saving something or nothing.
2. If we decide they admit saving nothing, then they also save less than $50,000$.  If we decided that they admit saving something, that they would further say that they saved less than $50,000$

Let me know if this helps.

*note: technically, they are frequencies, not probabilities, but this makes no difference to your problem here.